# Mule 3.7 how do I access inbound HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: mule

I have an http listener and the data that gets posted to it comes in as HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.  How do I access this?  I've output #[message], #[payload], and also inboundAttachments and I just can't figure out how to get to the data.

Comment: Are you talking about the HTTP headers ? Can you give an example of what data you need to access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the payload you are passing in your POST method , you can simply use the following expression in a logger :- `<logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO"/>`, or alternately you can use `<object-to-string-transformer>` after HTTP listener and then use a logger like `<logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO"/>`
The payload after the HTTP listener is in *inputstream* format so you need to convert it as a String

Comment: Thanks.  This led me to discover that since the data being posted is a soap document, I needed to use <dom-to-xml-transfomer> which then gave me access to the actual data I needed in #[payload]

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to check if you can access any data from mule Http endpoint is to place an empty logger , it prints all the data on the console and you can choose the data fro there .

```
 `INFO  2016-06-08 10:18:59,339 [[test].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]    org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage
{
  id=505d9b40-2d34-11e6-9b78-8cdcd4d3ab0f
  payload=org.mule.transport.NullPayload
  correlationId=<not set>
  correlationGroup=-1
  correlationSeq=-1
  encoding=UTF-8
  exceptionPayload=<not set>

Message properties:
  INVOCATION scoped properties:
  INBOUND scoped properties:
  accept=*/*
  accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8
cache-control=no-cache
connection=keep-alive
host=localhost:8084
http.listener.path=/
http.method=GET
http.query.params=ParameterMap{[]}
http.query.string=
http.relative.path=/
http.remote.address=/127.0.0.1:58506
http.request.path=/
http.request.uri=/
http.scheme=http
http.uri.params=ParameterMap{[]}
http.version=HTTP/1.1
postman-token=78bda747-9e48-66ab-bcd1-6dac20387f12
user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
  OUTBOUND scoped properties:
  SESSION scoped properties:
}
```

`

Comment: Thank you, Naveen .  I already knew this one, but still great information!